# Can I use environment variables in the pre-command and post-command in BackupExec jobs?

Tags: backup

I'm using BackupExec 12.5, and need to run some pre- and post-command scripts on my jobs.

I have several servers, some need the commands, some don't, but I don't want to create several policies, as they can be a bit complex.

I assume one solution is to create a common script on every server, perhaps in C:\BackupScripts\pre.bat for example, and do server-specific stuff in each one.

How do I handle servers without a C: drive (such as our Citrix servers)?  Can I use the %SYSTEMDRIVE% or %WINDIR% variables in the job setup?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that the path is relative to the installation of the BE agent, so in the worst case I could just put the script in that location and just put "pre.bat" in the option box.

Of course that script can be something simple that calls the 'real' script somewhere else - I don't like storing important custom scripts buried in the Program Files path of a third-party application.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen anything in the BE documentation that would suggest that this is possible. My recommendation would be to set up a test job and see.

Comment: Yeah, I did that and it doesn't work.  Looks like separate jobs.